# how to show user is online or not using action cable in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have developed a chat application in Rails-5
it is working fine but i want to show which user in on-line and which not.
using rails Action Cable.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and post some code demonstrating what you've done to solve your own problem. Stack Overflow users don't respond well to questions that simply state a desired behavior, without either a demonstration of effort or details that help narrow down the possible answers.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, i'm having the same problem... should i ask the same question again?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a general idea to acheive this**

1. Add is_online:boolean  field to user table
2. Then in your channel when user subscribes then update is_online field value to 1
3. When user unsuscribes then set is_online field to 0
4. Now you can check user.is_online? then display whether the user is online or not.

Comment: But when user login both subscribed and unsubscripted method called, but at the time of logout, only subscribed method called.. then how to updated with 0

Comment: Just simply give a if condition to check if user logged in and then perform change in status when user  logout the only value should update to 0

Comment: At the time of subscription, only subscribed method called.

Comment: @ManojRorAndr how do you get user in channel?

Comment: This will not work, because you will get race condition if one user open two tabs/connections... Because when one tab/connection will be closed database will be updated with is_online: false, but user will be online in another tab.

Comment: This will not work, because when rails app will crash, database will hold users online until they will connect/disconnect... Wich will not always be the case and you will get online ghosts...

Comment: If this doesn't work then there can be another idea which can make this task easy. Create separate table called onlineusers then when user login then insert user record into that table and automatically delete the record when user doesn't remain in contact with server more than one minute